# Tensorflow initialize a sparse tensor with only one line/column not zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I would like to initialize a sparse Matrix but specifying one line not zero(TF1.14):

Like

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],   
      ...,  
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

or

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],   
      ...,  
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I see the [SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor) do the similar things, but the problem is it needs to manually specify all the indices of every element that is not zero(I want to specify simply a row or a column), is there any more easier way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to create such a tensor, even for the general multidimensional case. You can use a function like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def line_tensor(shape, idx, axis=0, dtype=tf.float32):
    shape = tf.convert_to_tensor(shape)
    s_before = tf.concat([shape[:axis], [idx], shape[axis + 1:]], axis=0)
    s_line = tf.concat([shape[:axis], [1], shape[axis + 1:]], axis=0)
    s_after = tf.concat([shape[:axis], [shape[axis] - idx - 1], shape[axis + 1:]], axis=0)
    return tf.concat([tf.zeros(s_before, dtype), tf.ones(s_line, dtype),
                      tf.zeros(s_after, dtype)], axis=axis)

print(line_tensor([3, 4], 2, axis=0, dtype=tf.int32).numpy())
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1]]
print(line_tensor([3, 4], 1, axis=1, dtype=tf.int32).numpy())
# [[0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]]
```

If you prefer to create a sparse tensor, it is not hard either, although it is a bit trickier for the multidimensional case. Here is a simpler function just for matrices:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Assumes 2D shape
def line_matrix_sp(shape, idx, axis=0, dtype=tf.float32):
    shape = tf.dtypes.cast(shape, tf.int64)
    n = shape[1 - idx]
    idx1 = tf.range(n)
    idx2 = tf.fill([n], tf.dtypes.cast(idx, tf.int64))
    idx = tf.gather(tf.stack([idx1, idx2], axis=1), [1 - axis, axis], axis=1)
    return tf.SparseTensor(idx, tf.ones([n], dtype), shape)

print(tf.sparse.to_dense(line_matrix_sp([3, 4], 2, axis=0, dtype=tf.int32)).numpy())
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1]]
print(tf.sparse.to_dense(line_matrix_sp([3, 4], 1, axis=1, dtype=tf.int32)).numpy())
# [[0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]]
```